# How to capture resize event of any DOM element in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two components.

1st components contain a `form` with `textara` control, and the 2nd component contains an `SVG` graph. When user adds more detailed in `textarea` control and due to that form element get resized, however, I want to detect it to make my `SVG` graph aligned to that change.

```
<div id="comp1"> 
<form action="/action_page.php" id="usrform">

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
Enter text here...</textarea>
</form>
<div>

<div id="comp2">
</div>
```

I want to detect changes whenever `comp1` get resized.

Comment: You can not `resize` is  not available to HTML elements. It is triggered only on window. There is a proposal to make it available to elements as well but its not in yet. Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides `HostListener` Decorator that declares a DOM event to listen for, and provides a handler method to run when that **window resize** event occurs.

as below

```
import {HostListener} from '@angular/core';

class AppComponent{
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  resize(event) {
    console.log(event);
 }
}
```

**If you want to trigger an resize event on div resize** then you can create `custom directive` as provided by https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event package. You can use that package directly or copy the `directive` source code from [here](https://github.com/vdolek/angular-resize-event/blob/master/projects/angular-resize-event/src/lib/resized.directive.ts) and use it in your project.

Comment: As I understood, window changes only detected when the browser got resized. In my case browser size not get changed, only one <div> is getting resized, which doesn’t fire this event.

Comment: Yes @kandarp, but I have added one package details, you can add that `package` or copy the `directive` file in you package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `(window:resize)` function.

```
<div id="comp1" (window:resize)="yourFunction($event)">  // <-- add this code fragment
<form action="/action_page.php" id="usrform">

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
Enter text here...</textarea>
</form>
<div>

<div id="comp2">
</div>
```

Comment: Should work. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-grid-list-cols-alprdz